# Trying to show that $R_{ij}=R_{kij}\ ^k=g^{km}R_{kijm}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'd like to attain the identity in the title. Before we start, let me introduce some definitions. Thank you. The book I currently use is the one written by John M. Lee on Riemannian manifolds.

> ... The most important such tensor is the ***Ricci curvature*** or ***Ricci tensor***, denoted by *Rc* (or often *Ric* in the literature), which is the covariant $2$-tensor field defined as the trace of curvature endomorphism on its first and last indices. Thus for vector fields $X,Y$,
> $$Rc(X,Y)=\mathrm{tr}(\ Z\mapsto R(Z,X)Y\ ).$$
> The components of *Rc* are usually denoted by $R_{ij}$, so that
> $$R_{ij}=R_{kij}\ ^k=g^{km}R_{kijm}.$$

I'm not worried about the second equality: just substitute $g_{ml}R_{kij}\ ^l$ for the components $R_{kijm}$ of the Riemann curvature tensor given by
$$Rm(X,Y,Z,W)=\left<R(X,Y)Z,W\right>_g.$$
We have used $R$ to denote the $(1,3)$-curvature tensor given by
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_Y Z-\nabla_Y\nabla_X Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z,$$
and its components can be determined by $R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k=R_{ijk}\ ^l\partial_l$. Now let us go back to the first equality $R_{ij}=R_{kij}\ ^k$. How could I attain this result? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what is $tr$ and how to calculate that?

Comment: The operator $\mathrm{tr}$ stands for the action of taking the trace of a $(1,1)$-tenor, but that's all I know about it.

Comment: My suggestion is to view the first equality as the definition of the Ricci tensor. You then need to verify that it is well-defined, independent of the tangent basis used. That follows by the fact that the trace of a $(1,1)$-tensor is independent of the basis.

Comment: [Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850658/definition-of-trace-of-linear-operator) here.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas came into my mind, but I'm not sure if they work. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me proofread. Thank you.

In terms of local coordinates $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^n$, we write
$$Rc=R_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j.$$
Then $\forall p\in M$,
\begin{align}
R_{ij}(p)&=Rc_p(\partial_i|_p,\partial_j|_p)\\
&=\textrm{tr}(\ [Z\mapsto R(Z,\partial_i)\partial_j]_p\ ).
\end{align}
To evaluate the trace, we identify the $(1,1)$-tensor in the parentheses with
a linear operator $F$ on $T_p M$ defined by
$$F:u^k\partial_k|_p\mapsto u^k R_{kij}\ ^\ell(p)\partial_\ell|_p.$$
Now the task can be done by finding the trace of this operator. And we agree that
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(F)&=\text{tr}\left(
\begin{matrix}
R_{1ij}\ ^1(p)&\cdots&R_{nij}\ ^1(p)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
R_{1ij}\ ^n(p)&\cdots&R_{nij}\ ^n(p)
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n R_{kij}\ ^k(p)\\
&=R_{kij}\ ^k(p).\tag{summation convention}
\end{align}
We then assert that
$$R_{ij}=R_{kij}\ ^k.$$